# TypeError: props.render is not a function (React hook form)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing methods as a prop in this form I am making with react-hook-form.
Its giving me (TypeError: props.render is not a function) when Controller is added in from react-hook-form. I cannot find any solutions online so any help is appreciated.

```js
import { useForm, FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form';
import FormInput from './CustomTextField';

const AddressForm = () => {
  const methods = useForm();

  return (
    <>
      
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form onSubmit=' '>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <FormInput required name='firstName' label='First name' />
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
import { useFormContext, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';


const FormInput = ({ name, label, required }) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();
  

  return (
    <>
      <Controller
        as={TextField}
        name={name}
        control={control}
        label={label}
        fullWidth
        required={required}
        
      />
    <>
  );
};

export default FormInput;
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace of the error? Where exactly is it thrown?

Comment: when I console.trace() in the browser is returns overrideMethod (annonymous) @react_devtools_backend

Comment: Where is `TextField` coming from, any chance you forgot to import it?

Comment: yes i do have TextField imported, I mistakenly removed it while trying to clean up the code to submit for this question.

Comment: I can see TextField passing as a function when imported from material-ui/core, currently debugging why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is arising either because you update your **react-hook-form** or new to **react-hook-form**

You just need to use **render** prop in **Controller** component

```
  <Controller
        render={({ field }) => (
          <input
            onChange={(e) => field.onChange(transform.output(e))}
            value={transform.input(field.value)}
          />
        )}
      />
```

or if you are using a third party Form library

```
import { Input, Select, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";
   <Controller
            render={({ field }) => (
              <Select {...field}>
                <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
              </Select>
            )}
            control={control}
            name="select"
            defaultValue={10}
          />
```

Comment: If you had some major customization on your app for react-hook-form, and don't want to use **render** prop, in that case, switch back to react-hook-form v6,  `6.2.0`

Comment: I'm also getting this error and it didn't work for me 

Answer (score 24):

Was stuck in somewhat similar problem,
you can try following changes in **FormInput** function:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useFormContext, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';


const FormInput = ({ name, label, required}) => {
const { control } = useFormContext();
   const isError = false;

return (
   <>
         <Controller
            control={control}
            name={name}
            render = {({ field})=> (
                <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    label={label}
                    required
                />
            )}
         />
   </>
 );
 }

export default FormInput;
```

hope this helps, else you can go through the [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/)

Comment: Thus far, as of react-hook-form v7+, this seems to be the proper and updated approach.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem (TypeError: props.render is not a function) with react-hook-form + react-select when I tried to reuse the same Controller component from an old project, and I fixed this way:

### Unchanged:

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Select from "react-select";
```

### From:

```
<Controller
  name="languages"
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: true }}
  as={Select}
  options={props.languageOptionsToSelect}
  defaultValue={props.languageDefaultValueToSelect}
  isMulti
/>;
```

### To:

```
<Controller
  name="languages"
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <Select
      {...field}
      options={props.languageOptionsToSelect}
      defaultValue={props.languageDefaultValueToSelect}
      isMulti
    />
  )}
/>;
```

It seems **render** prop in Controller component is **required** now.

Comment: Note: maybe you need to remove `defaultValue` from the `Select` to `Controller` to Hook Form recognize the unchanged values that were set on load when submit the form.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one!

```js
<Controller
  render={({ field }) => <TextField {...field} />}
  name={name}
  control={control}
  label={label}
  fullWidth
  required={required}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `render` as a prop in the `Controller` Component. Refer to the docs [here](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/#ControlledmixedwithUncontrolledComponents)

Comment: Either the `render` _or_ `as` prop is required, but OP provided `as`, so this may not be the issue (note that `render` is _not_ marked as required in the [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api#Controller), and check the [source](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/v6.15.1/src/controller.tsx)).

Comment: [`as` prop was removed in v7](https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/), so `render` should be used now.

Answer (score 3):

```
import React from 'react'
import { TextField, Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import { useFormContext, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'

const FormInput = ({ name, label, required }) => {
const { control } = useFormContext()

    return (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Controller
                control={control}
                name={name}
                render = {({ field})=> (
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        label={label}
                        required
                    />
                )}
            />
        </Grid>
    )
}

export default FormInput
```

Comment: When writing an answer please try to explain what you have done and why it may be better than any of the previous answers.

Answer (score 2):

It now requires a **render** props, try this on MUI:

```
<Controller
  render={({ field }) => ( 
  <TextField {...field} label={label} required={required}/>)}
  control={control}
  fullWidth
  name={name}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for May 2023,
In version 7 of `react-hook-form` there is not more support for prop `as`

The way I loved it is to use the answers here and roll back to the use of the prop `render`